# Protractor starts Firefox(with profile) but doesn't respond/run any of the code

Tags: firefox, automation, protractor, geckodriver

Problem is the web app i'm testing is behind 2 basic auths and requires a proxy.

I wanted to pass the two basic auths by adding AutoAuth addon in a FireFox profile and setting up that profile to load in my conf.js everytime I call a new instance of firefox.
Problem is FF starts and does not execute anything -> just stays blank.

My conf.js

```
    exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['./testScripts/*.js'],
  capabilities: {
   'browserName': 'firefox',
    firefoxPath: 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
   'args': ["-profile","C:/Users/QA/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/vp04m5l2.fireFoxTestAcc"]
    }
},
```

As soon as i add marionette: false , or I disable the firefox profile the code in my spec starts executing.Tested with directconnect true&false.

> Protractor Version 5.3.0
>  Firefox Version : 59.0b8
>  geckodriver
>   - v0.19.1
>  NPM - 5.6.0

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the gecko driver.

There is an open ticket in bugzilla - No connection to Marionette can be made due to unknown port for custom profile - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1421766

Consider using the following workaround: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1058#issuecomment-347952270